# MYSQL SUM Double Results

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have following SQL but the `SUM` returns unexpected value's.. I can't figure out how to correct it.

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(logs.amount*ei_relationships.itemprice) as spend, 
    SUM(log_users.amount) as recharged, 
    logs.cardid, 
    count(log_users.amount) as recharges 
FROM log_users
INNER JOIN logs ON logs.cardid = log_users.cardid
INNER JOIN ei_relationships ON ei_relationships.id = logs.ei_relationship_id
WHERE ei_relationships.event_id = 2 
GROUP BY logs.cardid 
ORDER BY recharged DESC
```

A `ei_relationship` has many logs and there are also many `log_users`. I tried different things but can't figure it out.

Comment: Why are you using `distinct`?

Comment: Before groupping - just select everything and make sure you get expected results. PS: using `DISTINCT` in 90% of cases means you're doing it wrong

Comment: Great, this was one of my test SQL's updated the post without the distinct. Zerkms can you provide and example?

Comment: Could you produce a small example for every table, the output your query returns for those examples, and the expected output? That would simplify things greatly. After all, we can't see, from where we are, what is happening on your computer. (Well, I can't anyway.) We could, of course, just sit and guess, but it seems to me we've already been sitting and guessing enough. :)